# How did the author conclude $A^{-1}(A-f'(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

In the proof of inverse function theorem, $\phi(\textbf{x})=\textbf{x}+A^{-1}(\textbf{y}-\textbf{f(x)).}$  Applying the derivative, $\phi'(\textbf{x})=I+A^{-1} \textbf{f'(x)}$. How did the Author concluded the underlined statement? I know $\phi'(\textbf{x})=A^{-1}\circ A+A^{-1} \textbf{f'(x)}.$ First part is composition. Second part is multiplication. Can you help me to conclude $A^{-1}(A-f'(x))$?

Comment: Factor $A^{-1}$ on the left. That's it.

Comment: but one is multiplication of two operator, other one is composition.

Comment: Matrix multuplication corresponds to composition.

Comment: But it is a linear transformation!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the space of linear transformations from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ is isomorphic to the space of the matrices of $n$ lines and $m$ columns. That is, a linear transformation behaves exactly like a matrix, with composition being the multiplication of the matrices. Take a look in any introductory text on Linear Algebra.